# Как работает класс CameraPreview?

Tags: java, android, камера

Для работы с камерой в Android пишут вот такой класс:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        // create the surface and start camera preview
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error setting camera preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }
    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }
    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    // start preview with new settings
    setCamera(camera);
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error starting camera preview:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
    refreshCamera(mCamera);
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    //method to set a camera instance
    mCamera = camera;
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // mCamera.release();

}
```

}

Потом создаем объект этого класса и устанавливаем в LinnearLeaouyt как View элемент.

Что делают функции этого класса:

```
public void surfaceCreated()
public void refreshCamera()
public void surfaceChanged()
public void surfaceDestroyed()
```

Comment: `пишут вот такой класс` - вам виднее, что они делают, вы же пишете этот класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти три метода обязан реализовать класс, имплементирующий интерфейс [`SurfaceHolder.Callback`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html). Интерфейс обеспечивает контроль трех состояний (при наступлении определенных событий, срабатывают соответствующие методы обратного вызова):

`surfaceCreated()` - Вызывается при первом обращении к `SurfaceView`. Здесь вы можете разместить код, который будет выполнен, когда область отображения `SurfaceView` будет создана. В данном случае код запускает "картинку" с камеры.

`surfaceChanged()` - вызывается, когда с областью отображения произошли какие то изменения. Изменен размер области отображения  и тп. В данном случае вызывается метод `refreshCamera()` (см.далее).

`surfaceDestroyed()` - вызывается перед уничтожением области отображения.  В данном случае он ничего не делает, хотя мог бы зарелизить камеру, к примеру, чтобы освободить ресурсы (почему то закомментировано).

Собственный метод класса:

`refreshCamera()` - перезапускает "картинку" с камеры. За счет вызова в колбэке  `surfaceChanged()` корректно отрабатываются изменения параметров (размера, ориентации и тд.)

Comment: Как повернуть изображение? У меня когда телефон вертикально то картинка отображается вверх ногами и задом на перед, а когда горизонтально, то просто вверх ногами...